# How to horizontally center an inline (Run) comparing to other inlines in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I have `TextBlock` in which I put 2 `Inline`s (`Run`s), the `HorizontalAlignment` of the TextBlock is set to Center, this is ok, I just want to center the first Run comparing to the second, here's my code :

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="/Throne;component/Fonts/#Segoe UI Light" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding UserNameTextBlockVisibility}">
    <Run FontSize="25">En tant que :</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="ForestGreen"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Here's the result I get :

[image]

What I want to achieve :

[image]

I tried to search around the documentation and in threads on the internet, but I didn't really find a way to achieve this, how can I realize that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `TextAlignment="Center"` on your TextBlock

```
 <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="/Throne;component/Fonts/#Segoe UI Light" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="{Binding UserNameTextBlockVisibility}">
    <Run FontSize="25">En tant que :</Run>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Text="{Binding UserName}" Foreground="ForestGreen"/>
</TextBlock>
```